# Same Conditionals Not Working on Two Different Hooks

Tags: filters, hooks, wp-enqueue-script, actions, conditional-tags

Everyone!
I am new to WP and trying to build a plugin. I have the following codes working properly:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'say_hello');
function say_hello($content){
    if(is_single() || is_page()){
        print $content." Thank you for reading!";
    } else {
        print $content;
    }
}
```

But the following codes don't seem to work:

```
add_action('init', 'prepare_head');
function prepare_head(){
    if(is_single() || is_page()){
        // include javascripts
        wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
        //some more js goes here (registered and enqueued)... 

        //include css
        $styleSrc = plugins_url("css/style.css", __FILE__);
        wp_register_style("say_hello_style", $styleSrc);
        wp_enqueue_style("say_hello_style");
    }
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` is too early for [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), use `template_redirect` instead. have a look at the [action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to see the order they're executed.

Comment: Thanks! Worked. Since I am new to WP, could you recommend any good book (or link) that talks in details about ALL hooks?

Comment: @abhisek: actions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference, filters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference, book: http://justintadlock.com/plugindevbook

Answer (score 2):

The [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) that WordPress offers can only be used on the `template_redirect` hook or later. `init` is far too soon. The `the_content` filter occurs later on and can use the Conditional Tags. As you are new to WordPress plugins, take a look at [Rarst's graphical](http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-core-load/) explanation of how the WordPress core loads. It will help with these types of issues.